# how to create template file for single page in drupal 7

Tags: 7, theming

i have created "about us" page in drupal 7 admin interface of basic page type. I want to apply a specific layout for this "about us" page only.

But after goggling, i found solution of applying specific theme to specific content type like

page--content_type.tpl.php.

i dont want to apply layout for all pages in that content type, but only for this specific page "about us". If this can be done by overriding like this "page--node--nodeid.tpl.php", then where to find the nodeid for this page.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

use "page--node--nodeid.tpl.php" template. you can find the nodeid for this page when editing.

edit "about us" page, you will got url like this `http://www.example.com/node/1/edit`

digit "1" in the url is node-id.